# Add a tab bar using ESTabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add a tab bar to my application. The page that I've added the tab bar to is constantly refreshing itself. My `customAnimateRemindStyle3()` function is constantly being called. What should I do?

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)     
       self.present(AppDelegate.customAnimateRemindStyle3(implies: false), animated: false, completion: nil)   
  }
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
static func customAnimateRemindStyle3(implies: Bool) -> ExampleNavigationController {
        let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
        if let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as? ESTabBar {
            tabBar.itemCustomPositioning = .fillIncludeSeparator
        }
        let v1 = MainTableViewController()
        let v2 = MainTableViewController()
        let v3 = MainTableViewController()
        let v4 = MainTableViewController()
        let v5 = MainTableViewController()

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleAnimateTipsContentView3(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleAnimateTipsContentView3(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "find"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "find_1"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleAnimateTipsContentView3.init(specialWithAutoImplies: implies), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "photo_big"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_big_1"))
        v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleAnimateTipsContentView3(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "favor"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "favor_1"))
        v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleAnimateTipsContentView3(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "me"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "me_1"))

        tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]

        if let tabBarItem = v2.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2 ) {
                tabBarItem.badgeValue = "1"
            }
        }

        let navigationController = ExampleNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)
        return navigationController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is happening because you are presenting a new `ExampleNavigationController` that contains `MainTableViewController` on `ViewWillAppear` of `MainTableViewController`

To put it simply you are **Recursively** calling to present the `MainTableViewController` over and over again

What you can do here is

Firstly **REMOVE** this line form `ViewWillAppear`

```
self.present(AppDelegate.customAnimateRemindStyle3(implies: false), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Then in App-delegate present The `TabBarController` to begin with

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = AppDelegate.customAnimateRemindStyle3(implies: false), animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: I have one more defined rootviewcontroller.   let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainTableViewController())
window?.rootViewController = navigationController.  When I add this, the application does not work the way I want it to. Can't we add this Tabbar to rootview right now?

Comment: @stakbeko What is the way you want to? i'm not clear. What is that you dont want after changing to the above code?

Comment: I have another rootviewcontroller. They're not working together. I want to run rootview that I wrote in the code after you said rootview should work

Comment: Is the other rootViewController also `MainTableViewController`?

Comment: Yes, true. I want Tabbar added after Maintableview is opened.

Comment: So you want to show the user the `MainTableViewController ` first and then show the tab bar with some kind of animation? do i get the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I log out of the application and close the application, I am currently logged in from the login page. But when I add Tabbar's rootview, it does not open the home page, but it opens the tabbar page. That's why there's no rootview. So I want Tabbar to be added When maintableviewcontroller is opened.

Comment: so why are you using `MainTableViewController ` as your home page? just show the `HomePageController`(make a new one if you havn't already) then move the `customAnimateRemindStyle3` line to that `ViewWillAppear`

Comment: I'm already using the maintableviewcontroller as homepage. When I add it to viewwillappear, there is a problem.

Comment: that exaclty what im saying dont use that as Home (rootViewController) make a new `ViewContoller`